# June 2017: Most widely used and accepted Ethereum development framework on MacOSx?

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx, command-line

For those getting started with Ethereum development, is there any insight to be offered for which framework to use for mac?

There is also this post: [Which one is suitable frameworks for Dapp development(Truffle, Embark, Dapple)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/which-one-is-suitable-frameworks-for-dapp-developmenttruffle-embark-dapple) . Though it does not have an accepted answer or offer much insight.

Thanks for helping getting us started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a Macbook Pro for development. I use geth for running live/testnet nodes, and testrpc for local blockchains. I also use Truffle for creating/deploying smart contracts, and Node.js/React/web3 for creating web apps to interact with my smart contracts.

There is no "framework" to use for Mac specifically, you use whatever framework is more comfortable or easy to install/use on your machine.

Comment: Thanks @thomas_shal. That's what I was looking for. I understand your "no 'framework' to use for Mac" comment, just didn't want a linux-only answer.

Comment: just curious are you using `geth --fast --cache=512` on your macbook?